# Get a value of the kettle pentaho flow

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm working with the pentaho data integration, Spoon.

Short description: I want to get the number of times a value has appeared in the flow for each line that reads from the flow.

Long description: I am doing the transformation of the fact table, and when I read the data of a csv file, I have a client has traveled in a certain airplane at a specific time. I want to add a column, available seats, that whenever it appears read a data that a customer travels in a concrete airplane, look in the previous flow what is the number of seats available of that airplane and subtract 1.

Example.

Initially Flight 1 has 160 seats available and Flight 2 has 320 seats available.

```
CSV

Flight | Client

1      |   1

2      |   2

1      |   3

2      |   4
```

I can add a column that the value is the total of available seats.

```
Flight | Customer | Available seats

1      |     1    |        160

2      |     2    |        320

1      |     3    |        160

2      |     4    |        320
```

but afterwards i do not know how to obtain the minimum value of the seats available given a certain flight in each reading of the flow.

Final output I want in my flow..

```
Flight | Customer | Available seats

1      |     1    |        159

2      |     2    |        319

1      |     3    |        158

2      |     4    |        318
```

Many thanks in advance for the time in read my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Add value fields changing sequence` (available under the "Transform" steps group) step to generate a counter for each flight. The step will require the input to be sorted by `Flight` field. And you will need to specify `Flight` field in this step, so that the counter will be reset, once the new group of flights will start.

Then you will be able to subtract the counter from `Available seats` field to get the current value using Calculator/JavaScript/Java formula or any other step.

[image]

Here is an example, which you can copy and paste onto Spoon canvas:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transformation-steps>
<steps>
  <step>
    <name>Add value fields changing sequence</name>
    <type>FieldsChangeSequence</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
      <start>1</start>
      <increment>1</increment>
      <resultfieldName>counter</resultfieldName>
    <fields>
      <field>
        <name>Flight</name>
        </field>
      </fields>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>352</xloc>
      <yloc>96</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Data Grid</name>
    <type>DataGrid</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <fields>
      <field>
        <name>Flight</name>
        <type>Integer</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>Customer</name>
        <type>Integer</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>Total available seats</name>
        <type>Integer</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
    </fields>
    <data>
      <line> <item>1</item><item>1</item><item>160</item> </line>
      <line> <item>2</item><item>2</item><item>320</item> </line>
      <line> <item>1</item><item>3</item><item>160</item> </line>
      <line> <item>2</item><item>4</item><item>320</item> </line>
    </data>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>80</xloc>
      <yloc>96</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Sort rows &#x28;by flight&#x29;</name>
    <type>SortRows</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
      <directory>&#x25;&#x25;java.io.tmpdir&#x25;&#x25;</directory>
      <prefix>out</prefix>
      <sort_size>1000000</sort_size>
      <free_memory/>
      <compress>N</compress>
      <compress_variable/>
      <unique_rows>N</unique_rows>
    <fields>
      <field>
        <name>Flight</name>
        <ascending>Y</ascending>
        <case_sensitive>N</case_sensitive>
        <collator_enabled>N</collator_enabled>
        <collator_strength>0</collator_strength>
        <presorted>N</presorted>
      </field>
    </fields>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>192</xloc>
      <yloc>96</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Calculator</name>
    <type>Calculator</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <calculation>
      <field_name>Available seats</field_name>
      <calc_type>SUBTRACT</calc_type>
      <field_a>Total available seats</field_a>
      <field_b>counter</field_b>
      <field_c/>
      <value_type>Integer</value_type>
      <value_length>-1</value_length>
      <value_precision>-1</value_precision>
      <remove>N</remove>
      <conversion_mask/>
      <decimal_symbol/>
      <grouping_symbol/>
      <currency_symbol/>
    </calculation>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>496</xloc>
      <yloc>96</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

</steps>
<order>
    <hop>
      <from>Add value fields changing sequence</from>
      <to>Calculator</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>

    <hop>
      <from>Data Grid</from>
      <to>Sort rows &#x28;by flight&#x29;</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>

    <hop>
      <from>Sort rows &#x28;by flight&#x29;</from>
      <to>Add value fields changing sequence</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>

</order>
<notepads>
</notepads>
<step_error_handling>
</step_error_handling>
</transformation-steps>
```